# Must declare scalar var ... using dynamic tablename

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a variable tablename in the following SQL, but I keep getting

> Must Declare scalar variable @Projectnr

on executing from C# program.

The values are passed by the program, I'm sure this is somewhere in this SQL that things are mixed up...

this is the SQL:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_ProjectWerktijden]

   @Projectnr               VARCHAR(50),
   @Tasknr                  VARCHAR(50),
   @Datum                   DATETIME,
   @Startuur                DATETIME,
   @Einduur                 DATETIME,
   @WerktijdDEC             float,
   @TijdTijd                DATETIME,
   @Scanner                 VARCHAR(50),
   @StartID                 int,
   @EindID                  int,
   @Functiecode             int,
   @Naam                    varchar(100),
   @table                   NVARCHAR(50)



AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql= 'INSERT INTO **TABLE**
  ( 
        Projectnr, 
        Taaknummer,
        Datum,
        Start,
        Einde,
        Tijd,
        TijdTijd,
        Scanner,
        StartID,
        EindID,
        Functiecode,
        Naam
)
VALUES
(
@Projectnr,@Tasknr,@Datum,@Startuur,@Einduur,@WerktijdDEC,@TijdTijd,@Scanner,@StartID,@EindID,@Functiecode,@Naam
)
';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '**TABLE**', @table);
EXECUTE(@sql);
END
```

and the C# code

```
public static void TijdSaven(string projectnr, string tasknr, DateTime datum, DateTime? start, DateTime? einde, double tijd, DateTime tijdtijd,string scanner, int beginid, int eindid,int functiecode,string naam,string table) 
{ 
  if (tasknr.Contains("X")) { tasknr = "n.v.t.";} 
  ctx = new DataClassesDataContext();              
  ctx.sp_Insert_ProjectWerktijden(projectnr, tasknr, datum, start, einde, tijd, tijdtijd, scanner, beginid, eindid,functiecode,naam,table); 
  ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` and pass it all your input variables.

Comment: Lucas, can you provide an example please?

Comment: The problem is with your c# code and all you share is SQL code. How do you expect others to provide solution?

Comment: Raticik, the code is fine, have checked that twice. When it breaks on the exception I can see the values that are passed to the SP. They are all there.

Comment: public static void TijdSaven(string projectnr, string tasknr, DateTime datum, DateTime? start, DateTime? einde,
            double tijd, DateTime tijdtijd,string scanner, int beginid, int eindid,int functiecode,string naam,string table)
        {
            if (tasknr.Contains("X"))
            {
                tasknr = "n.v.t.";}
            ctx = new DataClassesDataContext();
            ctx.sp_Insert_ProjectWerktijden(projectnr, tasknr, datum, start, einde, tijd, tijdtijd, scanner, beginid, eindid,functiecode,naam,table);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }

Comment: @user3005015 gofr1 took care of that ;)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `PRINT(@sql)` before executing you will see that query to run is:

```
INSERT INTO **TABLE**
  ( 
        Projectnr, 
        Taaknummer,
        Datum,
        Start,
        Einde,
        Tijd,
        TijdTijd,
        Scanner,
        StartID,
        EindID,
        Functiecode,
        Naam
)
VALUES
(
@Projectnr,@Tasknr,@Datum,@Startuur,@Einduur,@WerktijdDEC,@TijdTijd,@Scanner,@StartID,@EindID,@Functiecode,@Naam
)
```

In this query there is no declaration to your variables, that is why you are getting error.

Instead of `EXECUTE(@sql);` better use parameters:

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(MAX); 

SET @ParmDefinition = N'   
@Projectnr VARCHAR(50),
@Tasknr VARCHAR(50),
@Datum DATETIME,
@Startuur DATETIME,
@Einduur DATETIME,
@WerktijdDEC float,
@TijdTijd DATETIME,
@Scanner VARCHAR(50),
@StartID int,
@EindID int,
@Functiecode int,
@Naam varchar(100)
'; 
--I guess table name must be replaced, you cannot use parameter for that one
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '**TABLE**', QUOTENAME(@table));

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, 
                            @Projectnr = @Projectnr,
                            @Tasknr = @Tasknr,
                            @Datum = @Datum,
                            @Startuur = @Startuur,
                            @Einduur = @Einduur,
                            @WerktijdDEC = @WerktijdDEC,
                            @TijdTijd = @TijdTijd,
                            @Scanner = @Scanner,
                            @StartID = @StartID,
                            @EindID = @EindID,
                            @Functiecode = @Functiecode,
                            @Naam = @Naam
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).